# Window Flicker While Positioning itself in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am working on a WPF application, the problem that i am facing is Screen Flickers, like it is positioning itself while loading. I want to hide it or something else like that until it loads completly, then display it.

I am trying to use recursive message pumping to do so, same as DoEvents in winform applications.

Something like

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new ThreadStart(delegate{});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use own DoEvents method like this one:

```
public void DoEvents()
{
    DispatcherFrame frame = new DispatcherFrame();
    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (Action<DispatcherFrame>)(frm => { frm.Continue = false; }), frame);
    Dispatcher.PushFrame(frame);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i believe last line should be Dispatcher.PushFrame(f); and my application stucks on that line, never come back. Kindly verify